# AWS IAM policy not working to restrict user to launch an instance in a particular VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I have a IAM policy that restricts a user to launch an instance in a particular VPC.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:accountID:instance/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:*:image/* ",
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:accountID:subnet/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:accountID:vpc/vpc-ID",
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:accountID:network-interface/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:accountID:volume/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:accountID:key-pair/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:accountID:tags/*",
        "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-2:accountID:security-group/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1394644402000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:CreateSecurityGroup"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1394645330000",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:AllocateAddress",
        "ec2:AssociateAddress",
        "ec2:ReleaseAddress"
        "ec2:AttachVolume",
        "ec2:CreateVolume",
        "ec2:CreateTags"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But the policy is not working. Also I want to restrict user from launching an instance in the ec2-classic.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You aren't explicitly denying that privilege to the user in this script. What are you expecting this script to be able to do?  Have you tried using the [IAM policy simulator](https://policysim.aws.amazon.com/)?

Comment: I want that user should be able to launch the instance in a particular instance and at the same time he should not be able to launch in the ec2-classic instance. The policy is not working. I have tried this

Comment: Did you manage to find any solution for this? As far as I see, it's NOT possible to achieve this (after hours of trying) without forbidding the users to create new security groups.